# Receiving from a channel into nowhere

Tags: go

Too often, reading at Go source code, I encounter this pattern where a value is received from a channel, something such as `<-doneC`, it does not save the result to a variable.

I don't understand what it does.

```
doneC, _, err := rest.XReceive(eHandler, errHandler)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error",err)
    return
}
<-doneC
```

Comment: `<-doneC` will block the current goroutine until some other goroutine does a send to that same channel, then the code will proceed. Basically it's "wait here until done".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an idiomatic way to implement an asynchronous wait in Go.

A function starts a new goroutine and returns a "done" channel to the caller.

The caller then does `<-doneC` which is basically an attempt to [receive](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) from the channel, ignoring the result.

The goroutine, when finished, can then either send a dummy value to `doneC` or, better yet, simply [`close`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Close) it. That acts as the signal for `<-doneC` to resume execution.

The added benefit of closing `doneC` instead of sending a dummy value is that (1) multiple calls to `<-doneC` can be unblocked at the same time, and (2) if none are waiting, the sending will block, but `close` won't.